Where can I find a list of all zugzwang positions with ≤ 5 pieces?
Is there a list of all zugzwangs with ≤ 5 pieces on the board? (Pawns and kings count as pieces)
If there are too many, maybe there is a list of all zugzwangs with ≤ 4 on the board?

full-point zugzwang or half-point zugzwang ?

@Evargalo both types

what is the difference. or the defintions. Zugzwang itself not always having the same defition everywhere, although in endgame that is where one can use the strict defition. I never hear of values zugzwang types.

John Beasley has a file containing information about his list of zugzwang positions with up to 6 units. That list is in a 15MB zip file zug3456.zip. (I mean that the zip is itself 15MB; the result of unzipping will be much larger.) There is a link to it from its parent directory.
